# SQOOP Not able to import table

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, sqoop2

I am running below command on sqoop

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/hadoopguide --table widgets
```

my version of sqoop : **Sqoop 1.4.4.2.0.6.1-101**
Hadoop -- **Hadoop 2.2.0.2.0.6.0-101**

Both taken from hortonworks distribution. all the paths like HADOOP_HOME, HCAT_HOME, SQOOP_HOME are set properly. I am able to get list of databases, list of tables from mysql database by running list-database, list-tables commands in sqoop. Even able to get data from --query 'select * from widgets'; but when i use --table option getting below error.

```
14/02/06 14:02:17 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local177721176_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class widgets not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:403)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class widgets not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1720)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBConfiguration.getInputClass(DBConfiguration.java:394)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat.createDBRecordReader(DataDrivenDBInputFormat.java:233)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.createRecordReader(DBInputFormat.java:236)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.<init>(MapTask.java:491)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:734)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:339)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:235)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class widgets not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1626)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1718)
        ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 6):

Specify the `--bindir` where the compiled code and `.jar` file should be located.

Without these arguments, Sqoop would place the generated Java source file in your current working directory and the compiled `.class` file and `.jar` file in `/tmp/sqoop-<username>/compile`.

Comment: I searched the whole internet and finally found only your solution works. Tears! Thank you so much!

The command is this:


sqoop import --connect jdbc:postgresql://<ip_address>:<port_num>/<db_name>  --username <db_username> -password <db_password> --table <table_name> --bindir /tmp/sqoop-<ubuntu_username>/compile/ --delete-target-dir

Answer (score 6):

Use the `--bindir` option and point to your current working directory.

```
sqoop import --bindir ./ --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/hadoopguide --table widgets
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is resolved after i copied the .class file from /tmp/sqoop-hduser/compile/ to hdfs /home/hduser/ and also the current working directory from where i am running sqoop.

Answer (score 0):

For importing a specific table into `hdfs`, run:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/databasename --username root --password *** --table tablename --bindir /usr/lib/sqoop/lib/ --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --target-dir /directory-name
```

Make sure that `/usr/lib/sqoop/*` and `/usr/local/hadoop/*` should be owned by the same user otherwise it will give error like **"Permission denied"**.

**PS**: Make sure that you have installed `mysql-java` connector before you run the command. *I installed hadoop version 2.7.3 and connector 5.0.8*

Answer (score 0):

Another fix for ClassNotFoundException is to tell Hadoop to use the user classpath first (-Dmapreduce.job.user.classpath.first=true).  This can be on command line or in Options file.  The top of an import Options file would be:

```
#Options file for Sqoop import
import

-Dmapreduce.job.user.classpath.first=true
```

This fixed ClassNotFoundException for me when trying to import data as-avrodatafile