# Importing data from MySQL to HDFS: ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, mysql, mapreduce, sqoop, hadoop2

I am trying to import "employee" table from "Employee" database of MySQL using Sqoop in Hadoop. I am using Hadoop version "2.7.1", Sqoop version "1.4.6", JDK version "1.8.0_111", MySQL version is "5.7.17". I have started all the Hadoop services. But when I try to import table from mysql database I am getting exception.

I already tried with the approaches mentioned in  [SQOOP Not able to import table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21599785/sqoop-not-able-to-import-table?noredirect=1&lq=1) to solve my problem, but none of them worked for me.

The installation path of sqoop is: `/usr/local/sqoop/`

**The command that I am using to import the data is:**

```
bin/sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Employee --table employee --username root --password root --m 1 --target-dir /user/sqoop/sqlimport/employee
```

**And the exception that I am getting is:**

```
Warning: /usr/local/sqoop/bin/../../hbase does not exist! HBase imports will fail.
Please set $HBASE_HOME to the root of your HBase installation.
Warning: /usr/local/sqoop/bin/../../hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will fail.
Please set $HCAT_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.
Warning: /usr/local/sqoop/bin/../../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
Warning: /usr/local/sqoop/bin/../../zookeeper does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ZOOKEEPER_HOME to the root of your Zookeeper installation.
17/02/06 16:44:15 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6
17/02/06 16:44:15 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
17/02/06 16:44:15 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
17/02/06 16:44:15 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
Mon Feb 06 16:44:15 GMT 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
17/02/06 16:44:16 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `employee` AS t LIMIT 1
17/02/06 16:44:16 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `employee` AS t LIMIT 1
17/02/06 16:44:16 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.1
Note: /tmp/sqoop-hduser/compile/f278f3a3c2014397621b675f68a94873/employee.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
17/02/06 16:44:17 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-hduser/compile/f278f3a3c2014397621b675f68a94873/employee.jar
17/02/06 16:44:17 WARN manager.MySQLManager: It looks like you are importing from mysql.
17/02/06 16:44:17 WARN manager.MySQLManager: This transfer can be faster! Use the --direct
17/02/06 16:44:17 WARN manager.MySQLManager: option to exercise a MySQL-specific fast path.
17/02/06 16:44:17 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Setting zero DATETIME behavior to convertToNull (mysql)
17/02/06 16:44:17 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning import of employee
17/02/06 16:44:17 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
17/02/06 16:44:17 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/02/06 16:44:17 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
17/02/06 16:44:18 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
17/02/06 16:44:18 INFO Configuration.deprecation: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
17/02/06 16:44:18 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
Mon Feb 06 16:44:18 GMT 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
17/02/06 16:44:18 INFO db.DBInputFormat: Using read commited transaction isolation
17/02/06 16:44:18 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
17/02/06 16:44:18 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_local819205273_0001
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458978/parquet-avro-1.4.1.jar <- /usr/local/sqoop/bin/parquet-avro-1.4.1.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized file:/usr/local/sqoop/lib/parquet-avro-1.4.1.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458978/parquet-avro-1.4.1.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458979/parquet-generator-1.4.1.jar <- /usr/local/sqoop/bin/parquet-generator-1.4.1.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized file:/usr/local/sqoop/lib/parquet-generator-1.4.1.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458979/parquet-generator-1.4.1.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458980/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar <- /usr/local/sqoop/bin/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized file:/usr/local/sqoop/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458980/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458981/jackson-annotations-2.3.0.jar <- /usr/local/sqoop/bin/jackson-annotations-2.3.0.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized file:/usr/local/sqoop/lib/jackson-annotations-2.3.0.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458981/jackson-annotations-2.3.0.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458982/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar <- /usr/local/sqoop/bin/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized file:/usr/local/sqoop/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458982/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458983/parquet-jackson-1.4.1.jar <- /usr/local/sqoop/bin/parquet-jackson-1.4.1.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized file:/usr/local/sqoop/lib/parquet-jackson-1.4.1.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458983/parquet-jackson-1.4.1.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458984/jackson-databind-2.3.1.jar <- /usr/local/sqoop/bin/jackson-databind-2.3.1.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized file:/usr/local/sqoop/lib/jackson-databind-2.3.1.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458984/jackson-databind-2.3.1.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458985/parquet-column-1.4.1.jar <- /usr/local/sqoop/bin/parquet-column-1.4.1.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized file:/usr/local/sqoop/lib/parquet-column-1.4.1.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458985/parquet-column-1.4.1.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458986/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar <- /usr/local/sqoop/bin/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized file:/usr/local/sqoop/lib/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458986/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458987/kite-data-core-1.0.0.jar <- /usr/local/sqoop/bin/kite-data-core-1.0.0.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized file:/usr/local/sqoop/lib/kite-data-core-1.0.0.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458987/kite-data-core-1.0.0.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458988/parquet-format-2.0.0.jar <- /usr/local/sqoop/bin/parquet-format-2.0.0.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized file:/usr/local/sqoop/lib/parquet-format-2.0.0.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458988/parquet-format-2.0.0.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458989/ant-eclipse-1.0-jvm1.2.jar <- /usr/local/sqoop/bin/ant-eclipse-1.0-jvm1.2.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized file:/usr/local/sqoop/lib/ant-eclipse-1.0-jvm1.2.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458989/ant-eclipse-1.0-jvm1.2.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458990/parquet-hadoop-1.4.1.jar <- /usr/local/sqoop/bin/parquet-hadoop-1.4.1.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized file:/usr/local/sqoop/lib/parquet-hadoop-1.4.1.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458990/parquet-hadoop-1.4.1.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458991/commons-jexl-2.1.1.jar <- /usr/local/sqoop/bin/commons-jexl-2.1.1.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized file:/usr/local/sqoop/lib/commons-jexl-2.1.1.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458991/commons-jexl-2.1.1.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458992/sqoop-1.4.6.jar <- /usr/local/sqoop/bin/sqoop-1.4.6.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized file:/usr/local/sqoop/sqoop-1.4.6.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458992/sqoop-1.4.6.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458993/opencsv-2.3.jar <- /usr/local/sqoop/bin/opencsv-2.3.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized file:/usr/local/sqoop/lib/opencsv-2.3.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458993/opencsv-2.3.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458994/parquet-encoding-1.4.1.jar <- /usr/local/sqoop/bin/parquet-encoding-1.4.1.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized file:/usr/local/sqoop/lib/parquet-encoding-1.4.1.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458994/parquet-encoding-1.4.1.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458995/snappy-java-1.0.5.jar <- /usr/local/sqoop/bin/snappy-java-1.0.5.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized file:/usr/local/sqoop/lib/snappy-java-1.0.5.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458995/snappy-java-1.0.5.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458996/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar <- /usr/local/sqoop/bin/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized file:/usr/local/sqoop/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458996/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458997/avro-mapred-1.7.5-hadoop2.jar <- /usr/local/sqoop/bin/avro-mapred-1.7.5-hadoop2.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized file:/usr/local/sqoop/lib/avro-mapred-1.7.5-hadoop2.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458997/avro-mapred-1.7.5-hadoop2.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458998/jackson-core-2.3.1.jar <- /usr/local/sqoop/bin/jackson-core-2.3.1.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized file:/usr/local/sqoop/lib/jackson-core-2.3.1.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458998/jackson-core-2.3.1.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458999/parquet-common-1.4.1.jar <- /usr/local/sqoop/bin/parquet-common-1.4.1.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized file:/usr/local/sqoop/lib/parquet-common-1.4.1.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458999/parquet-common-1.4.1.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399459000/kite-data-hive-1.0.0.jar <- /usr/local/sqoop/bin/kite-data-hive-1.0.0.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized file:/usr/local/sqoop/lib/kite-data-hive-1.0.0.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399459000/kite-data-hive-1.0.0.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399459001/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar <- /usr/local/sqoop/bin/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized file:/usr/local/sqoop/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399459001/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399459002/commons-io-1.4.jar <- /usr/local/sqoop/bin/commons-io-1.4.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized file:/usr/local/sqoop/lib/commons-io-1.4.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399459002/commons-io-1.4.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399459003/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar <- /usr/local/sqoop/bin/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized file:/usr/local/sqoop/lib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399459003/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399459004/kite-hadoop-compatibility-1.0.0.jar <- /usr/local/sqoop/bin/kite-hadoop-compatibility-1.0.0.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized file:/usr/local/sqoop/lib/kite-hadoop-compatibility-1.0.0.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399459004/kite-hadoop-compatibility-1.0.0.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399459005/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar <- /usr/local/sqoop/bin/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized file:/usr/local/sqoop/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399459005/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399459006/kite-data-mapreduce-1.0.0.jar <- /usr/local/sqoop/bin/kite-data-mapreduce-1.0.0.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized file:/usr/local/sqoop/lib/kite-data-mapreduce-1.0.0.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399459006/kite-data-mapreduce-1.0.0.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399459007/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar <- /usr/local/sqoop/bin/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized file:/usr/local/sqoop/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399459007/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399459008/paranamer-2.3.jar <- /usr/local/sqoop/bin/paranamer-2.3.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized file:/usr/local/sqoop/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399459008/paranamer-2.3.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399459009/xz-1.0.jar <- /usr/local/sqoop/bin/xz-1.0.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized file:/usr/local/sqoop/lib/xz-1.0.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399459009/xz-1.0.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399459010/commons-codec-1.4.jar <- /usr/local/sqoop/bin/commons-codec-1.4.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized file:/usr/local/sqoop/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399459010/commons-codec-1.4.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399459011/avro-1.7.5.jar <- /usr/local/sqoop/bin/avro-1.7.5.jar
17/02/06 16:44:19 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized file:/usr/local/sqoop/lib/avro-1.7.5.jar as file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399459011/avro-1.7.5.jar
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458978/parquet-avro-1.4.1.jar
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458979/parquet-generator-1.4.1.jar
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458980/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458981/jackson-annotations-2.3.0.jar
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458982/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458983/parquet-jackson-1.4.1.jar
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458984/jackson-databind-2.3.1.jar
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458985/parquet-column-1.4.1.jar
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458986/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458987/kite-data-core-1.0.0.jar
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458988/parquet-format-2.0.0.jar
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458989/ant-eclipse-1.0-jvm1.2.jar
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458990/parquet-hadoop-1.4.1.jar
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458991/commons-jexl-2.1.1.jar
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458992/sqoop-1.4.6.jar
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458993/opencsv-2.3.jar
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458994/parquet-encoding-1.4.1.jar
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458995/snappy-java-1.0.5.jar
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458996/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458997/avro-mapred-1.7.5-hadoop2.jar
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458998/jackson-core-2.3.1.jar
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399458999/parquet-common-1.4.1.jar
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399459000/kite-data-hive-1.0.0.jar
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399459001/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399459002/commons-io-1.4.jar
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399459003/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399459004/kite-hadoop-compatibility-1.0.0.jar
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399459005/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399459006/kite-data-mapreduce-1.0.0.jar
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399459007/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399459008/paranamer-2.3.jar
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399459009/xz-1.0.jar
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399459010/commons-codec-1.4.jar
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/1486399459011/avro-1.7.5.jar
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://localhost:8080/
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_local819205273_0001
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter set in config null
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for map tasks
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local819205273_0001_m_000000_0
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
Mon Feb 06 16:44:20 GMT 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO db.DBInputFormat: Using read commited transaction isolation
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: 1=1 AND 1=1
17/02/06 16:44:20 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map task executor complete.
17/02/06 16:44:20 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local819205273_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class employee not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class employee not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2195)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBConfiguration.getInputClass(DBConfiguration.java:403)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat.createDBRecordReader(DataDrivenDBInputFormat.java:237)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.createRecordReader(DBInputFormat.java:263)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.<init>(MapTask.java:515)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:758)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class employee not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2193)
    ... 12 more
17/02/06 16:44:21 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local819205273_0001 running in uber mode : false
17/02/06 16:44:21 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
17/02/06 16:44:21 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local819205273_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: NA
17/02/06 16:44:21 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
17/02/06 16:44:21 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group FileSystemCounters is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.FileSystemCounter instead
17/02/06 16:44:21 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 0 bytes in 2.7879 seconds (0 bytes/sec)
17/02/06 16:44:21 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter instead
17/02/06 16:44:21 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 0 records.
17/02/06 16:44:21 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Error during import: Import job failed!
```

**Note:**

I have installed Hadoop and its related tools from a separate user "hduser" in a group "hdgroup".

Comment: run with `--outdir java_files` option and see if errors goes away....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQOOP Not able to import table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21599785/sqoop-not-able-to-import-table)

Comment: @RonakPatel, I tried with `bin/sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Employee --table employee --username root --password root --m 1 --target-dir /user/sqoop/sqlimport/employee --outdir java_files`, but still I am getting the same exception again.

Comment: @ossu54, I already tried with all the related posts including the one that you mentioned here, but none of them solved my problem.

Comment: mysql jar reference done in sqoop ?

Comment: @karthik, Yes its already done. I have `mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar` in `/usr/local/sqoop/lib` path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending many hours on this problem I found the solution myself. I need to use the `--bindir` option to point to the installation directory of sqoop, to inform the sqoop service from where it should pick the jar files.

Command that worked for me to import the data from MySQL to HDFS is:

```
bin/sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Employee --username root --password root --m 1  --table employee --bindir /usr/local/sqoop/ --target-dir /user/sqoop/sqlimport/employee
```

Command that worked for me to export the data from HDFS to MySQL is:

```
bin/sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Employee --username root --password root --m 1 --table employeeexported --bindir /usr/local/sqoop/ --export-dir /user/sqoop/sqlimport/employee/part-m-00000
```